mechanisms for handing functions with multiple optional parameters
I'm writing a library where there will be some functions that take many (more than 50) parameters (not my design but I need to model it).
I want to minimise the pain for the caller calling these functions, taking a simple example:
type Person = 
    {   name : string option 
        address : string option
    }

how can I create these records with the least pain.
Attempt 1 (consciously bad)
module Person = 
    let make : string option -> string option -> Person = 
        fun name address ->
            {   name = name
                address = address
            }

let p1 = Person.make (Some "Jim") None


this is how I would often write such code, but obviously the issue here is with many many parameters the client call to create a person would have lots of "Some" and "None", painful
Attempt 2 (from microsoft documention)
type Person = 
    {   name : string option 
        address : string option
    }
    static member make (?name : string,?address : string) = 
        {   name = name 
            address = address
        }

let p1 = Person.make(name = "bill bloggs")

This is better, but I've suddenly had to flip my style to use explicit static members, I don't have a massive problem with this, but I wouldn't want to mix the previous style with this style based on how I feel. I could write all my code like this, but if feels unidiomatic of F#.
Attempt 3 (can't remember where I saw this)
type Person2 = 
    {   name : string option 
        address : string option
    }

module Person2 = 
    let make (setter : Person2 -> Person2) = 
        setter { name = None; address = None }


let p2 = Person2.make (fun p -> { p with name = Some "bill bloggs" })

This uses the record update syntax to optionally 'update' parameters with default values.
It preserves the idiomatic style of attempt 1, but really is more 'noisy' than attempt 2.
Question:
which of these is idiomatic? (or is another style idiomatic not listed)?

Other ideas (used in github.com/jet/* quite a bit - https://github.com/jet/FsKafka/blob/master/src/FsKafka/FsKafka.fs is a decent example, but I applied that lots of other places in having APIs with lots of options without reams of fluent trainwreck support code)
type Person(?name, ?address) =
    ()

And/or you can chain constructors and add some logic/helpers on top of that:
type Person(?name, ?address) =
    new(?name, ?address) = Person(name = name, address = address)

If you definitely want records and you don't have a good reason for a module, I'd stick with the factory method on the type as a type's Methods can have optional args whereas a module's functions do not make that possible. (And don't use lower case method names, you'll hate yourself eventually if you do!)
type Person =
    { name: string option; address: string option }
    static member Create(?name, ?address): Person =
        { name = name; address = address }


yeah, I'm inconsistent with my use of upper/lowercase.
I find it irksome that you cant do this with 'let' bindings.....I may just adopt this static method though everywhere.

this is my attempt 2 really, but I think thats the way I'll go for the moment.

fair point - I only skimmed your post ;) IME managing configs via a default record that you then manipulate via an associated module tends to break down pretty quickly. Having said that, as Equinox, FsKafka and FsCodec show, things can get a touch messy once you accommodate some complexities. It's easy to forget thought that wading through reams of fluent builder logic or finding hard to discover helper modules is not free either - a static member Create can do a lot. One final thing to mention is that for C# interop, you need to put an [<Optional>] on your ?xyz args for C# to respect it

I like record update syntax, but without the noise. Just break out the "empty" instance as a starter:
type Person = 
    {
        name : string option 
        address : string option
    }
    
let empty =
    {
        name = None
        address = None
    }
    
let p3 =
    { empty with
        name = Some "bill bloggs" }


ah ok, I like to have a function that makes the record, one way or another, hmmmm....let me try that out for size though

its not really a 'proper' question, lets see what else turns up, though I think its a useful summary of how to do this in various ways

I've marked the other response as the answer, not because its more 'correct' just that it fits my intention at this time...it is in fact the same as my "attempt 2", I've been writing F# for 10 years ish, on and off, and I struggle for a standard style even now.

+1 this is a clean approach and is definitely the most idiomatic F#. As such it's definitely a decent default to start with. More importantly, doing that will encourage you to break down the overall design into simpler components; IME its only when you're combining/not disentangling potentially separable concepts that this gets cumbersome -- thus staring with this can be a helpful nudge to a good design.
